# Combine two MySQL queries with shared results?

Tags: mysql

Okay, so I have a query:

```
SELECT *, articles.article_date AS article_date
FROM articles
    INNER JOIN thread ON (thread.thread_id = articles.thread_id)
WHERE articles.article_date < 1417987751
```

This query gets all results from `articles` table and joins them with data from the `thread` table. As you can see, an article can not be returned if it does not have a matching thread entry.

Now I have another query:

```
SELECT *, thread.post_date AS article_date
FROM thread
    LEFT JOIN articles ON (articles.thread_id = thread.thread_id)
WHERE articles.article_date IS NULL
    AND thread.post_date < 1417987751
    AND thread.node_id IN ('66','78')
```

This query gets all results from the `thread` table that come from nodes `66` and `78`, that DO NOT have a matching `article` entry. So an thread CAN be returned, and will be returned, ONLY if it doesn't have a matching article entry. heoretically, these queries should not have matching data.

I then need to combine both these results, and `ORDER BY article_date LIMIT 5`.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: you mean by using `UNION`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you can do it this way:

```
SELECT *, COALESCE (articles.article_date, thread.post_date) AS _article_date
FROM thread
LEFT JOIN articles ON (articles.thread_id = thread.thread_id)
WHERE
  (articles.article_date is not NULL AND articles.article_date < 1417987751)
  OR (articles.article_date IS NULL
    AND thread.post_date < 1417987751
    AND thread.node_id IN ('66','78'))
ORDER BY
_article_date
LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check below query

```
SELECT *, thread.post_date AS article_date
FROM thread 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT *
        FROM articles 
        ORDER BY article_date LIMIT 5) articles 
    ON (articles.thread_id = thread.thread_id)
WHERE thread.post_date < 1417987751
AND thread.node_id IN ('66','78');
```

Comment: That doesn't do it. Notice that the `article_date` is different in both queries.

Comment: This also has a major fault. If an article exists, but is NOT in nodes `66` or `78`, it won't get returned in this query. The first query I posted does not have a node restriction, only the second one does.